# Simplify an if else construct with assignment before if and else

Tags: python, optimization, graph

I want to simplify an `if: .. else: ..` construct:

```
def find_eulerian_tour(graph):
    available_edges, path = initial_state(graph)
    while incomplete(available_edges):
        edge = propose_extension_edge(available_edges, path)
        if extension_is_possible(edge):
            extend_path(available_edges, path, edge)
        else: 
            node = propose_node_for_reorder(available_edges, path)
            if reorder_is_sensible(node):
                path = reorder_path(available_edges, path, node)
            else:
                return None
    return path
```

It seems unnecessarily complicated, because the idea can be expressed much simpler.

```
def find_eulerian_tour(graph):
    available_edges, path = initial_state(graph)
    while incomplete(available_edges):
        if extension_is_possible(available_edges, path):
            extend_path(available_edges, path)
        elif reorder_is_sensible(available_edges, path):
            path = reorder_path(available_edges, path)
        else:
            return None
    return path
```

But now I have to do the calculations from

```
edge = propose_extension_edge(available_edges, path)
```

and

```
node = propose_node_for_reorder(available_edges, path)
```

twice because I can't keep the results in variables (edge = .., node = ..).

I am looking for an idea to keep code as simple as it is with the `elif` construction while doing the `propose_node..`-calculation only once.

```
def find_eulerian_tour(graph):
    available_edges, path = initial_state(graph)
    while incomplete(available_edges):
        edge = propose_extension_edge(available_edges, path)
        if extension_is_possible(edge):
            extend_path(available_edges, path, edge)
        else: 
            node = propose_node_for_reorder(available_edges, path)
            if reorder_is_sensible(node):
                path = reorder_path(available_edges, path, node)
            else:
                return None
    return path

def initial_state(graph):
    available, path = graph[:], []
    if len(available) > 0:
        path.append(available[0][0])
    return available, path

def incomplete(available_edges):
    return len(available_edges) > 0

def propose_extension_edge(available_edges, path):
    last_node = path[-1]
    for edge in available_edges:
        if last_node in edge:
            return edge
    return None

def extension_is_possible(edge):
    return edge

def extend_path(available_edges, path, edge):
    if edge[0] == path[-1]:
        path.append(edge[1])
    else:
        path.append(edge[0])
    available_edges.remove(edge)

def propose_node_for_reorder(available_edges, path):
    if reorder_is_possible(path):
        return find_split(available_edges, path)
    return None

def reorder_is_possible(path):
    return is_tour(path)

def find_split(available_edges, path):
    options = edgenodes(available_edges)
    for node in options:
        if node in path:
            return node
    return None

def reorder_is_sensible(node):
    return node

def is_tour(path):
    return path[0] == path[-1]

def edgenodes(edges):
    result = []
    for edge in edges:
        for node in edge:
            if not node in result:
                result.append(node)
    return result

def reorder_path(available_edges, tour, split):
    split_location = tour.index(split)
    return tour[split_location:-1] + tour[0:split_location+1]
```

Example use:

```
graph1 = [(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 1)]
graph2 = [(0, 1), (1, 5), (1, 7), (4, 5), (4, 8), (1, 6), (3, 7), (5, 9), (2, 4), (0, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6), (8, 9)]
graph3 = [(1, 13), (1, 6), (6, 11), (3, 13), (8, 13), (0, 6), (8, 9),(5, 9), (2, 6), (6, 10), (7, 9), (1, 12), (4, 12), (5, 14), (0, 1), (2, 3), (4, 11), (6, 9), (7, 14), (10, 13)]

print find_eulerian_tour(graph1)
print find_eulerian_tour(graph2)
print find_eulerian_tour(graph3)
```

Comment: I rarely use python. I do a course on algorithms with exercises in python. And I see this as chance to improve the readability of my python code by the way.

Answer (score 1):

```
def find_eulerian_tour(graph):
    available_edges, path = initial_state(graph)
    while incomplete(available_edges):
        edge = propose_extension_edge(available_edges, path)
        if extension_is_possible(edge):
            extend_path(available_edges, path, edge)
        else: 
            node = propose_node_for_reorder(available_edges, path)
            if reorder_is_sensible(node):
                path = reorder_path(available_edges, path, node)
            else:
                return None
    return path
```

Since you are inside a `while` block, an `if`-`else` can be turned into `if`->`continue`. The inner `if`-`else` can be turned into `if not`->`return`:

```
def find_eulerian_tour(graph):
    available_edges, path = initial_state(graph)
    while incomplete(available_edges):
        edge = propose_extension_edge(available_edges, path)
        if extension_is_possible(edge):
            extend_path(available_edges, path, edge)
            continue
        node = propose_node_for_reorder(available_edges, path)
        if not reorder_is_sensible(node):
            return None
        path = reorder_path(available_edges, path, node)
    return path
```

Now it reads like a checklist:

- Extension possible? Do that and continue.
- Reordering not sensible? Quit.
- Reorder.

Is it an improvement? On the original: I think so. Nested logic is generally more difficult to follow. On the `if`-`elif`-`else`? Not really, but that's the price to pay for caching the intermediary values.

Comment: It is an improvement on the original. Thanks

Comment: The `if not` idea is good. I think I can expand it. Bad luck, I must make a break now. I am back in ca. 3 hours and will then check if it works out.

Answer (score 0):

With the `if not` proposed by otus and with the shortcut logic of `or` I can write

```
def find_eulerian_tour(graph):
    available_edges, path = initial_state(graph)
    while incomplete(available_edges):
        if not (extension_success(available_edges, path) or
                reorder_success(available_edges, path)):
            return None
    return path
```

The `.._success` functions are new. They calculate a proposal and, if this is successful, they mutate the status, i.e. `path` and `available_edges`. 
I am aware that mutation can be difficult to follow too. But as I already use mutation in the extend.. case, it is only consistent to also use mutation in the reorder.. case.

At least at this moment I am happy with this refactoring.

```
def find_eulerian_tour(graph):
    available_edges, path = initial_state(graph)
    while incomplete(available_edges):
        if not (extension_success(available_edges, path) or
                reorder_success(available_edges, path)):
            return None
    return path

def initial_state(graph):
    available, path = graph[:], []
    if len(available) > 0:
        path.append(available[0][0])
    return available, path

def incomplete(available_edges):
    return len(available_edges) > 0

def extension_success(available_edges, path):
    edge = propose_extension_edge(available_edges, path)
    if not extension_is_possible(edge): return False
    return extend_path(available_edges, path, edge)

def propose_extension_edge(available_edges, path):
    last_node = path[-1]
    for edge in available_edges:
        if last_node in edge:
            return edge
    return None

def extension_is_possible(edge):
    return edge

def extend_path(available_edges, path, edge):
    if edge[0] == path[-1]:
        path.append(edge[1])
    else:
        path.append(edge[0])
    available_edges.remove(edge)
    return True

def reorder_success(available_edges, path):
    node = propose_node_for_reorder(available_edges, path)
    if not reorder_is_sensible(node): return False
    path[:] = reorder_path(available_edges, path, node)
    return True

def propose_node_for_reorder(available_edges, path):
    if reorder_is_possible(path):
        return find_split(available_edges, path)
    return None

def reorder_is_possible(path):
    return is_tour(path)

def find_split(available_edges, path):
    options = edgenodes(available_edges)
    for node in options:
        if node in path:
            return node
    return None

def reorder_is_sensible(node):
    return node

def is_tour(path):
    return path[0] == path[-1]

def edgenodes(edges):
    result = []
    for edge in edges:
        for node in edge:
            if not node in result:
                result.append(node)
    return result

def reorder_path(available_edges, tour, split):
    split_location = tour.index(split)
    return tour[split_location:-1] + tour[0:split_location+1]
```